# Selecting indexes from Multidimensional Array where the value is 0 is not working

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Please i am given a task to return an indexes from a 2d array that is frequently updating. Actually is an assignment on the 2048 game . When ever, a random numb is added, i want it added randomly to the free/empty tiles as it should be. Thats where the array value is 0 in my case.

```
private static int[][] addTile()
 {
            rd = new Random();
            int px, py;
            px = rd.Next(0, 4);
            py = rd.Next(0, 4);

            List<int> availableInd =  randPosition(py);
            int r = rd.Next(0, availableInd.Count);
            int newPx = availableInd[0];
            if (Tiles[py][newPx] == 0)
            {
                Tiles[py][newPx] = rd.Next(0, 20) == 0 ? rd.Next(0, 15) == 0 ? 8 : 4 : 2;
            }
            else
            {
                py = py; // I put a break here
            }
}
```

My randPosition() method loks like the fflg;

```
public static List<int> randPosition(int num)
        {
            List<int> indexes = new List<int>();

            //  var emptyTiles = arr.Where(x => x == 0).ToList();
            indexes = Tiles[num].Select((s, index) => new { s, index })
                      .Where(x => x.s == 0)
                      .Select(x => x.index)
                      .ToList();

            if (indexes.Count > 0)
                return indexes;

            //Incase The above fails. I would seach row by row
            //for an empty tile
            for (int c = 0; c < Tiles.Count(); c++)
            {
                indexes = Tiles[c].Select((s, index) => new { s, index })
                      .Where(x => x.s == 0)
                      .Select(x => x.index)
                      .ToList();

                if (indexes.Count > 0)
                    break;
            }


            return indexes;
        }
```

First i ramdomly generate my y-axis , i then pass it to the randPosition to check if there exist an empty cell in the said axis. If there are , get the indexes of the cells. IF there are not, i then perform an advance row by row search below to make sure only empty tiles are returned. However, when i put the break at the else of the first method, i realized still occupied tiles/cells are return as empty. I tried alot of manipulations yet to no avail. please where do i go wrong ? How do i best handle this ? Any help suggestion or alternative would highly be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat of a guess, but I think you have a logic error:

`randPosition(num)` is supposed to return the "empty" cells in row `num`.  If it does not find any, it searches row-by-row until it does find an empty cell.

The problem is, *the caller doesn't know if the original search failed*.  It's entirely possible that the indices returned represent cells of a completely different row than was asked for.  That may be why you see "occupied" cells returned as "empty".

Here's an analogy:

You're taking a trip to New York.  You go to the airport to book a flight (I know, no one does this anymore).  You ask for all empty seats on row 7 (because you like row 7).  The Customer Service Agent looks up row 7 and finds that there are no empty seats.  Instead of telling you that, she instead start looking through all other rows and finds an empty seat (C) on row 15.  So she tells you that "Seat C is empty".  The problem is, *you think she's talking about row 7*!  You have no indication that row 7 was full or which row she's referring to.

Either the caller needs to iterate through other rows (so that it knows which row the empty cells are on), or the method needs to have some sort of feedback that indicates *which* row the empty cells are on.

Comment: Thank you sir, Going through again. Also i learnt the linq metho from here sir. <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291788/linq-to-find-array-indexes-of-a-value">here</a>. Perhaps could i be missing something ? Nonetheless would continue to check

Comment: The linq method is likely not your problem.  The problem is that you're possibly returning indices related to a completely different column that what the caller is asking for.  Run it in the debugger and see if that's not the case.

Comment: Thank you sir you are right. It turns out the logic was wrong . When ever, the row i sen return empty , it proceed and search through below until it finds a arrow with empty records forgetting to update the row sent earlier on. Thank you sir.